# Yasso20 R implementation

Tags: r, model

I have been trying to run the Yasso20 model implementation for R (https://github.com/YASSOmodel/Yasso20/blob/main/model/Yasso20.r)

I am testing the function `Yasso20` with data from:
https://github.com/YASSOmodel/Ryassofortran/tree/master/data

as:

```
Yasso20(YParameters = sample_parameters,
        SimulationTime = sample_data_run$time, 
        MonthlyTemperature = sample_data_run$temp, 
        Precipitation = sample_data_run$prec, 
        InitialCPool = sample_data_run$init, 
        LitterInput = sample_data_run$litter, 
        WoodySize = sample_data_run$wsize, 
        leac = sample_data_run$leac, 
        SS_pred = TRUE)
```

but I get:

```
Error in if (tem <= 1e-16) { : the condition has length > 1
```

I thought that maybe this function is meant to be used in loop for each time step, so I tried then to test:

```
Yasso20(YParameters = sample_parameters,
        SimulationTime = sample_data_run$time[1], 
        MonthlyTemperature = sample_data_run$temp[1], 
        Precipitation = sample_data_run$prec[1], 
        InitialCPool = sample_data_run$init[1], 
        LitterInput = sample_data_run$litter[1], 
        WoodySize = sample_data_run$wsize[1], 
        leac = sample_data_run$leac[1], 
        SS_pred = TRUE)
```

getting a little farther:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.array': replacement has length zero
```

However, I am not sure this is the correct approch.
It seems to me that the input data should be formatted differently.

I am hoping somebody knows which sample data can be used to run this function, or which format it should have.

===================================

UPDATE 01.02.2024

I have noticed that in the original Fortran90 code, the temperature dependence is applied as:

```
tem = 0.0
temN = 0.0
temH = 0.0
DO i = 1,12 ! Average temperature and precipitation dependence
    tem = tem+EXP(theta(22)*temp(i)+theta(23)*temp(i)**2.0)
    temN = temN+EXP(theta(24)*temp(i)+theta(25)*temp(i)**2.0)
    temH = temH+EXP(theta(26)*temp(i)+theta(27)*temp(i)**2.0)
END DO
```

so I have modified the R `Yasso20` function with:

```
tem <- 0
temN <- 0
temH <- 0

for (i in 1:12) {
    tem <- tem + exp(theta[22] * T[,i] + theta[23] * T[i]^2)
    temN <- temN + exp(theta[24] * T[,i] + theta[25] * T[i]^2)
    temH <- temH + exp(theta[26] * T[,i] + theta[27] * T[i]^2)
}
```

Running the function with these parameters:

```
Yasso20(YParameters = sample_parameters,
        SimulationTime = sample_data_run$time[1],
        MonthlyTemperature = sample_data_run$temp[1,],
        Precipitation = sample_data_run$prec[1],
        InitialCPool = sample_data_run$init,
        LitterInput = sample_data_run$litter[1,],
        WoodySize = sample_data_run$wsize[1],
        leac = sample_data_run$leac[1], 
        SS_pred = TRUE)
```

works, but still I am not sure if this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code on GitHub, the inputs are mostly well described.  There is one problem you encountered.

```r
Error in if (tem <= 1e-16) { : the condition has length > 1
```

If you copy the GitHub code, if you change lines 68-72 to the following and then source the function in again, that will solve the error:

```r
  if(any(tem <= 1e-16)) 
  {
    xt <- init + b*t;
    return(xt);
  }
```

I then got the function to run with:

```r
Yasso20(YParameters = sample_parameters,
        SimulationTime = sample_data_run$time, 
        MonthlyTemperature = sample_data_run$temp[1,], 
        Precipitation = sample_data_run$prec[1], 
        InitialCPool = sample_data_run$init, 
        LitterInput = sample_data_run$litter[1,], 
        WoodySize = sample_data_run$wsize, 
        leac = sample_data_run$leac[1], 
        SS_pred = TRUE)
```

producing a vector of 5 zeros.  Whether this is the intended result or not, I have no idea.